# Reflections of one object displayed on another object

Tags: uv, shaders, reflection

First off, I am not sure how to title this question. If somebody has a suggestion for a more relevant title I will gladly change it.

My goal is to have one object in a scene display reflections that actually occur from another object in that scene.

[image]

See the example image above. It contains two planes and two spheres, rendered using the cycles engine. The sphere on the left correctly displays a reflection of the red and gray planes on the left and right respectively. Is there a way to take that reflection and apply it to the sphere on the right, so that the right sphere displays a reflection of the red and gray planes.

I do not know how to do that. Is there a way to export the current reflection as an image and apply it as an UV map to another object?

Comment: maybe you should explain a bit more what you want to achieve. From your image for me it looks like the gray plane "hides" the red plane so it cannot show the reflection. So how should the result look like? maybe you can help us with a sketch what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, there isn’t. I wish there was, though. It would make portals so much easier. You can fake it with compositing, but… Is there any other way to achieve what you’re looking for?

Comment: @Chris What I want is that both spheres look exactly identical. One sphere should have the correct reflections as per the scene, while the other is just an exact visual copy of the other sphere

Comment: The only work around that you could try is to render your scene using a panoramic camera and then use that as an HDRI world reflection.